# Firefox update fails with "not found" error

Tags: 10.04, firefox, synaptic

I got 3 update notifications for firefox:

[image]

Yet when I click update, it fails with a "not found" error:

[image]

Any idea why this is? How to fix this?

Comment: Choose another mirror, it's telling you right what's wrong 404 not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are failing to contact the US mirror so your update is failing.

Open a terminal or press Alt+F2 and type `gksu software-properties-gtk`, from the small drop down list try to change server to another country or select *Main Server* from the list, close the tool after your are done.

[image]

Upgrade with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `Download from:` to `Main server` (was US before) and it is now downloading package files. I wonder why the US servers have this problem.

Comment: Probably was only outdated package lists as the answer bellow says, feel free to return to the US mirror if you don't have any further issues. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by simply clicking the button to **check for updates** again. The package manager is looking for Firefox 9 but the binary is now version 10.

This happens when you automatically check for updates, the package version changes, and then you try to update on the stale information.

One you re-check, you will get the correct data & should be able to update with no issues.

If you are still having issues, try removing the firefox stable ppa.